# Create end of the month date from a date variable

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a large data frame with date variables, which reflect first day of the month. Is there an easy way to create a new data frame date variable that represents the last day of the month?

Below is some sample data:

```
date.start.month=seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),length=4,by="months")
df=data.frame(date.start.month)
df$date.start.month

"2012-01-01" "2012-02-01" "2012-03-01" "2012-04-01"
```

I would like to return a new variable with:

```
"2012-01-31" "2012-02-29" "2012-03-31" "2012-04-30"
```

I've tried the following but it was unsuccessful:

```
df$date.end.month=seq(df$date.start.month,length=1,by="+1 months")
```

Comment: Your example output doesn't fit with the question.

Comment: You could also consider using `"yearmon"` class which represents year/month without needing a day in the first place: `library(zoo); ym <- as.yearmon("2012-01") + 0:3/12` .   If you did want dates on the last day of the month then `as.Date(ym, frac = 1)`.

Comment: G.Grothendieck:  Thank you for your suggestion, I will ahve to remember to use the yearmon class for this type of date data in the future.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To get the end of months you could just create a `Date` vector containing the 1st of all the subsequent months and subtract 1 day.

```
date.end.month <- seq(as.Date("2012-02-01"),length=4,by="months")-1
date.end.month
[1] "2012-01-31" "2012-02-29" "2012-03-31" "2012-04-30"
```

Comment: Thanks James but this didnt seem to work within the data frame structure.

Comment: library(lubridate)

date.start.month=seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),length=4,by="months")
df=data.frame(date.start.month)
df$date.end.month=df$date.start.month+months(1)-days(1)

df$date.start.month
df$date.end.month

"2012-01-01" "2012-02-01" "2012-03-01" "2012-04-01"
"2012-01-31" "2012-02-29" "2012-03-31" "2012-04-30"

Comment: @MikeTP It looks like its working to me, but your example output was confusing: Why 27th April?

Comment: James: My appologies... the 27th of April was a typoand should have read "2012-04-30".  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 54):

Here is another solution using the [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf) package:

```
date.start.month=seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),length=4,by="months")
df=data.frame(date.start.month)

library(lubridate)
df$date.end.month <- ceiling_date(df$date.start.month, "month") - days(1)
df$date.end.month
[1] "2012-01-31" "2012-02-29" "2012-03-31" "2012-04-30"
```

This uses the same concept given by James above, in that it gets the first day of the next month and subtracts one day.

By the way, this will work even when the input date is not necessarily the first day of the month. So for example, today is the 27th of the month and it still returns the correct last day of the month:

```
ceiling_date(Sys.Date(), "month") - days(1)
[1] "2017-07-31"
```

Comment: ```days(1)``` is actually unnecessary. It is sufficient to do ```ceiling_date(Sys.Date(), "month") - 1```. Just for future visitors...

Answer (score 18):

Use timeLastDayInMonth from the [timeDate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/index.html) package:

```
df$eom <- timeLastDayInMonth(df$somedate)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
library(lubridate)
as.Date("2019-09-01") - days(1)
[1] "2019-08-31"
```

or

```
library(lubridate)
as.Date("2019-09-01") + months(1) - days(1)
[1] "2019-09-30"
```

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward solution would be using the `yearmon`function with the argument `frac=1` from the `xts`-package. `frac` is a number between 0 and 1 that indicates the fraction of the way through the period that the result represents.

```
as.Date(as.yearmon(seq.Date(as.Date('2017-02-01'),by='month',length.out = 6)),frac=1)

[1] "2017-02-28" "2017-03-31" "2017-04-30" "2017-05-31" "2017-06-30" "2017-07-31"
```

Or  if you prefer “piping” using `magrittr`:

```
seq.Date(as.Date('2017-02-01'),by='month',length.out = 6) %>%
         as.yearmon() %>% as.Date(,frac=1)

[1] "2017-02-28" "2017-03-31" "2017-04-30" "2017-05-31" "2017-06-30" "2017-07-31"
```

Answer (score 1):

A function as below would do the work (assume dt is scalar) -

```
month_end <- function(dt) {
    d <- seq(dt, dt+31, by="days")
    max(d[format(d,"%m")==format(dt,"%m")])
}
```

If you have a vector of Dates, then do the following -

```
sapply(dates, month_end)
```

Comment: This function is no good. Chuck in "2019-01-31" for example and it all falls apart.

Answer (score 1):

`tidyverse` has added the [clock](https://clock.r-lib.org/) package *in addition* to the `lubridate` package that has nice functionality for this:

```
library(clock)

date_build(2012, 1:12, 31, invalid = "previous")
# [1] "2012-01-31" "2012-02-29" "2012-03-31" "2012-04-30" "2012-05-31" "2012-06-30"
# [7] "2012-07-31" "2012-08-31" "2012-09-30" "2012-10-31" "2012-11-30" "2012-12-31"
```

The `invalid` argument specifies what to do with an invalid date (e.g. 2012-02-31). From the documentation:

> "previous": The previous valid instant in time.
>
> "previous-day": The previous valid day in time, keeping the time of
> day.
>
> "next": The next valid instant in time.
>
> "next-day": The next valid day in time, keeping the time of day.
>
> "overflow": Overflow by the number of days that the input is invalid
> by. Time of day is dropped.
>
> "overflow-day": Overflow by the number of days that the input is
> invalid by. Time of day is kept.
>
> "NA": Replace invalid dates with NA.
>
> "error": Error on invalid dates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `timeperiodsR`

```
date.start.month=seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),length=4,by="months")
df=data.frame(date.start.month)
df$date.start.month
```

```r
# install.packages("timeperiodsR") 

pm <- previous_month(df$date.start.month[1]) # get previous month

start(pm) # first day of previous month
end(pm)   # last day of previous month
seq(pm)   # vector with all days of previous month
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use [bsts::LastDayInMonth](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bsts/versions/0.9.2/topics/last.day.in.month):

```r
transform(df, date.end.month = bsts::LastDayInMonth(df$date.start.month))

#   date.start.month date.end.month
# 1       2012-01-01     2012-01-31
# 2       2012-02-01     2012-02-29
# 3       2012-03-01     2012-03-31
# 4       2012-04-01     2012-04-30
```