# Change date to the last day of month using days_in_month

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a character variable and I want to change it to a variable of class Date and change it to the last day of the month using days_in_month().

My character variable is currently in the form Year-Mo, e.g. 2017-01, 2017-02.

How would I do this using as.Date and days_in_month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question, because it's been asked many times!
Check out these answers:

[R calculate month end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772996/r-calculate-month-end)

[Create end of the month date from a date variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503896/create-end-of-the-month-date-from-a-date-variable)

The great part? Packages update all the time, so sometimes the answers no longer work. That's not the case here.

@Edgar Santos, at the first link, gave a detailed answer that fits your question perfectly.

```
library(lubridate)

dt <- c("2017-01","2017-02")  # data
dt <- ym(dt)                  # change to date of year-month format
day(dt) <- days_in_month(dt)  # update the 'day' in the date

[1] "2017-01-31" "2017-02-28"
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message when I try to knit to pdf saying 'could not find function "days_in_month"' do you know why this error message appearing

Comment: You asked this a long time ago, sorry about that! That function is in the package `lubridate`. if you received that error, you either haven't installed that package, called the library, or both.

Answer (score 2):

```r
vec <- c("2017-01", "2017-02")
dates <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(paste(vec, "01"), format = "%Y-%m %d"))
dates$mon <- dates$mon + 1
dates$mday <- dates$mday - 1
as.Date(dates)
# [1] "2017-01-31" "2017-02-28"
```